# Dribbling few drops of urine a few minutes after urinating but it's not incontinence (men)

Tags: taharah

Salam,

After urinating some few drops of urine come out of my body after i leave the bathroom, i'm not being delusional (it's not waswas), i can see drops on myself sometimes when i check. However there are two points that make me think that i don't have urinary incontinence , and that hence i cannot react the way i read on many forums before:

1. i am certain that it's not urinary incontinence because it only happens time to time
2. it happens only a few minutes after urinating and it's in very small amounts

To face the problem i know i must be certain that all the urine has left my urethra(istibra') and for that i tried to :

1. place a tissue in my underwear, however it moves out of place basically all the time which makes it useless (unless i fix it with a paperclip, which doesn't sounds to be a good solution). By the way, can't i just ignore if urine has dried on my underwear in such a way that i cannot find where the drop happened to fall?
2. standing up, walking around with me holding a tissue to collect the eventual drops
3. squeezing my penis which actually gives me an erection and hence make it even more difficult to empty the urethra.

None of these solutions seems to be the correct one : they're time consuming and not very efficient.

 The bad thing is that if i want to relieve myself but the prayer time is close, i hold myself back if it's not too hard because otherwise the last drops will make me waste time and be late for the prayer

 I said earlier that what i did didn't sound like a good solution, i said that because i feel like i'm doing too much (like when i was obsessed with purity until i learned to ignore uncertainty), also i learned that Allah doesn't not intend to make religion hard for us and this is why i think that i'm doing things wrong

 **To summarize: i need an answer for how to purify myself properly after urinating without getting inconvenient.** If you answer this please be as accurate as possible and give proofs and sources for each argument. Barakallahufikum

Answer (score 1):

I suffer from the same problem and what I find easiest is to urinate after reading salah. So I would go in the morning after I wake up. If I need to go till zuhr I’ll go and same for asr maghrib etc. I still think it would be best to go see a doctor to determain whether it is incontinence as there are rulings which make it easier for someone who suffers from incontinence.

To answer the question about urine on underwear is it stated in the hanafi fiqh that 5cm of liquid filth is excusable for someone who is madhur or suffers from incontinence hence why you should go get it checked out.